# Set AppDynamics integration with Python

Tags: python, dockerfile, appdynamics

I'm trying to set up my Python application to send data to AppDynamics. I have the AppDynamics controller up and running and on my local my application works, but no data is found on AppDynamics

I've been told to use this repo as a template (and I can confirm it works, sending data to the AppDynamics instance I'm working on) `https://github.com/jaymku/py-k8s-init-scar/blob/master/kube/web-api.yaml`

I have some doubts though, and they might be the cause of the issues that I'm having.

I had in my Dockerfile a CMD at the end like `first.sh && python3 second` and I've changed it to be ENTRYPOINT "first.sh && python3 second". Note no [] format here and also that there are two concatenated commands.

On the value of the `APP_ENTRY_POINT` variable I'm trying just the same.

There are no errors when I run this, my application works correctly, except the data is not sent to AppDynamics. Nothing seems to fail, I can't find any error messages. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Also, where can I find out, within AppDynamics, the value that we need to set for the APPDYNAMICS_CONTROLLER_PORT variable? I'm pretty sure it will be 443 in our case, since we seem to be using that in other proyects in AppDynamics that are working, but checking it would be a good idea. It might also be related with this issue, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to have this working by using CMD instead of ENTRYPOINT, using the command that is found inside the suggested entrypoint. So, I did the same that was supposed to done the entrypoint but inserting the command myself